# LockSupport.upark() can occur before LockSupport.park() method but in the follow code why it block the code

Tags: java

LockSupport.upark() can occur before LockSupport.park() method but in the  follow code why it  block the code.in my code ,in the main thread there are 4 LockSupport.unpark(t1),actually,it can  obtain only one access,when i run the thread t1,LockSupport.park() can consume one and return,but it block the code ,Why?

```
public class LockSupportDemo{
public static Object u = new Object();
static ChangeObjectThread t1 = new ChangeObjectThread("t1");
public static class ChangeObjectThread extends Thread{

    public ChangeObjectThread(String name)
    {
        super.setName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (u)
        {

            LockSupport.park(Thread.currentThread());
            System.out.println("in "+ getName());
            if(Thread.interrupted())
            {
                System.out.println(getName()+" interrupted");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(getName() +"isOver");

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    LockSupport.unpark(t1);
    LockSupport.unpark(t1);
    LockSupport.unpark(t1);
    LockSupport.unpark(t1);
    LockSupport.unpark(t1);
    t1.start();
 }
 }
```

Comment: Read the Javadoc for `LockSupport.unpark` again, especially the last sentence: *This operation is not guaranteed to have any effect at all **if the given thread has not been started.***

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for `LockSupport.unpark` is very explicit on this:

> Makes available the permit for the given thread, if it was not already
>   available.  If the thread was blocked on `park` then it will unblock. 
>   Otherwise, its next call to `park` is guaranteed not to block. *This
>   operation is not guaranteed to have any effect at all **if the given
>   thread has not been started.***

What you did above can't work.

To achieve the same, you could start the thread but have it wait until you call `unpark` in the main thread, by using `wait`/`notify` signalling, for example. Or if you needed something quick and dirty (since this seems to be more about exploring `LockSupport` than about writing production code), then you could even use `Thread.sleep(1000);` at the start of the `run` method.